# Mandatory Progress bar while fetching & showing data in listview

Tags: java, android

I am using below code to show progress bar when user clicks to get list of apps in mobile. Issue is this bar hardly appears, where as I noted it take 2 to 3 seconds to show the list of apps in activity.

```
 static private void prod() {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Fetching App List");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

    }
```

This is how I passing data to custom listview.

```
  Adapter = new AppListAdapter(context, packageList, packageManager);
        apps.setAdapter(Adapter);
```

and here I m calling progress dismiss like this in getView of Adapter class.

```
 AppList.procan();
        return convertView;
```

Does 2 to 3 second not sufficient to at least show progress bar.

I m calling this method on click and dismissing on when listview adapter is called.

I saw in many applications even for 1 sec of application show progress bar. Why not I could able to get. What fix can I do.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue could be initialization(time consuming) of ProgressDialog during every click so

1.) make method non-static and initialize the `progressDialog` in `oncreate` (or initialize it ASAP if it's in different class)

2.) Then only call `show` on the instance of `progressDialog`

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;;
protected void onCreate(...) {
   //...code
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Fetching App List");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...");

}

private void prod() {
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I did not get progress bar, but the time to fetch & show data is reduced drastically I believe because of change in initialization . Now it is showing list instantly around in 1 sec. Still any hope to show progress bar?

Comment: @Panache seems like 1 second is quite less for progress dialog to display and disappear though are you sure that you are only dismissing the progressdialog only after data retrieval, like in case of asynchronous   process

Comment: yes, if I remove progressDialog.dismiss on listadapter call, it start showing indefinitely. Even for 2 sec, it will not work?

Comment: it's bit confusing what you are saying without code, but only one thing required is, dialog should be dismissed once, the adapter has been linked with the listview

Comment: ..  the adapter has been linked with the listview or data has been added to adapter or datasource (list etc)

Comment: see update coded in question, may give you some idea to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166193/discussion-between-panache-and-pavneet-singh).